# App unable to read iCloud file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, icloud

I am developing a very simple app based on icloud. what it does is as follows:

- take the UbiquityContainer url and create/write a "plist" file there with some array.

When app installed first time on device it works totally fine. icloud can document can be observed in setting/ icloud section.

When i delete the app from device and install it again. It does not read the file. Shows the following error.

```
"The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad file descriptor"
```

I dont what I am missing. It is so disturbing.

**EDIT:** offsite code link removed.  Please edit your question and include the code throwing the error.

Please suggest solution...

Comment: I'd suggest you add a code snippet of what you do on a first install (so the clean creation), and how you check whether the plist is there already or not. Pretty hard to debug with what you've included here.

Comment: When you delete the app, do you also delete the settings: Settings App > iCloud > Storage and Backup > Manage Storage > Documents and Data - Show All....

Comment: @DavidDelMonte No i didn't delete from there.

Comment: @MichaelKernahan one link to the code is added to question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all does it work if you suspend the app and open it again?

1. Run the app.
2. Press the home button.
3. Start another app / wait a clouple of seconds.
4. re-open the app from the background.

Second: after deleting, check if the file is still present: https://developer.icloud.com/

Third: make sure that the full directory containing the file is downloaded before you try to acces it (from this post [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/316297-copy-from-icloud-to-sandbox-fails.html)).

Comment: First: It works that way. Second: yes the data is retain there at the icloud and can be downloaded(plist file.) Third: i will appreciate if you could refer the code in link given in the question.